# Dataframe Join in pyspark throwing Syntax Error

Tags: apache-spark, join, pyspark

In Pyspark, I am trying to join 2 dataframe to call all the column from both the dataframe.

The Key column in DataFrame1 = NUMBER and KeyColumn in DataFrame2 = POSNUM (Different Column name in two dataframe.)

```
Dataframe1:

NUMBER|NAME
++++++++++++++++++
23000|Fairchild                
23001|Philips                 
23002|Sony     
23003|Video                         
23004|Audio           
23005|Mobile 
+++++++++++++++++++

+++++++++++++++++++                   
NM|POSNUM
+++++++++++
PH|23000
RS|380094
QT|23002
AO|379962
DS|23004
TX|379964
NS|379965
+++++++++++++++++++


Output
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
23000|Fairchild|PH|23000
23002|Sony|QT|23002 
23004|Audio|DS|23004
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

**Code:**

```
df1.join(df2, df1.NUMBER == df2.POSNUM).show()
```

**Error:**

```
    raise IllegalArgumentException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: u'Unsupported class file major version 55'
```

Please help me, if i am missing anything.

Comment: maybe you have multiple versions of java running in your system. Please reinstall Java it will start working. Note: Based on the Spark version install Java(Eg: If you have Spark 2.3 in your system use java 8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error here is that your syntax for join is incorrect.

```py
df1.join(df2, df1.NUMBER == df2.POSNUM).show()
```

or you can use:

```py
df1.join(df2, df1['NUMBER'] == df2['POSNUM']).show()
```

Comment: Thanks Ravi, but unfortunately it is throwing error as "raise IllegalArgumentException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace) pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: u'Unsupported class file major version 55'". Please help –

Comment: ```python
df1 = spark.read.csv('/FileStore/tables/df1.txt',header=True,inferSchema=True,sep="|")
df2 = spark.read.csv('/FileStore/tables/df2.txt',header=True,inferSchema=True,sep="|")
df1.join(df2, df1.NUMBER == df2.POSNUM).show()
 
+------+--------------------+---+------+
|NUMBER|                NAME| NM|POSNUM|
+------+--------------------+---+------+
| 23000|Fairchild        ...| PH| 23000|
| 23002|           Sony     | QT| 23002|
| 23004|    Audio           | DS| 23004|
+------+--------------------+---+------+```

Answer (score 0):

You don't quote the names of the fields when you reference them. Instead of `"NUMBER"`, use `NUMBER`, etc, as follows:

```
df1.join(df2, df1.NUMBER == df2.POSNUM).show()
```

Comment: Thanks Jay, but unfortunately it is throwing error as "raise IllegalArgumentException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: u'Unsupported class file major version 55'". Please help

Comment: did you try `df1.join(df2, df1['NUMBER'] == df2['POSNUM']).show()` ?